# Spring Integration with standard Java EE Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, spring

How do I install and enable Eclipse Spring integration? I'm running Eclipse IDE for Java EE Developers 3.7.2. I've installed Spring IDE Core 2.6.0. Under Eclipse - Preferences, Spring appears in the menu, yet when I edit my spring XML file it doesn't recognize it as a Spring configuration file. Under Project - Properties I don't see any Spring settings. If I go to my Spring XML file - Properties, there's no Spring item in the left hand side. How do I tell Eclipse that an XML file is a Spring config file?

Comment: Have you tried installing the Spring Tool Suite?

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis Will that replace my Eclipse?

Comment: You might be right, it might be standalone. I don't have any Spring plugins on my eclipse, but it recognizes XML namespaces correctly. What do you mean by _spring XML file it doesn't recognize it as a Spring configuration file_?

Comment: What type of project you are created?

Comment: Just a normal Java project I created it a long time ago

Comment: "What do you mean by spring XML file it doesn't recognize it as a Spring configuration file" - I can type in an invalid class name and it doesn't care

Comment: So then what good is Spring IDE Core if it doesn't do anything?